Using a video tag with a 20Mb mp4 file works everywhere but not on iPhone
I add a video into the site as follows:
<video controls>
    <source src="66d0e5d820c31.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

It works on macOS, windows, android, using multiple browsers.
But on the iPhone (using iPhone 15), with Chrome and Safari, it just doesn't load. It shows the controls, and 00:00 in the timeline.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Does tapping one of the controls make it play?

(1) Does this alternate setup make it play?
<video controls playsinline muted autoplay>
    <source src="66d0e5d820c31.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

(2) Is your MP4 really an MP4? Eg: could it be just a WebM renamed to MP4? Use a tool/website like MediaInfo online to check the video file's actual codecs (a/v media types).
You want video type of AVC with codec of H.264 with YUV420p color space. 
HEVC with H.265 should also work on iOS video decoders.
